# Do I need to load the weights of another class I use in my NN class?

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I have a model that needs to implement self-attention and this is how I wrote my code:

```
class SelfAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.multihead_attn = torch.nn.MultiheadAttention(args)
        
    def foward(self, x):
        return self.multihead_attn.forward(x, x, x)
    
class ActualModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        self.inp_layer = nn.Linear(arg1, arg2)
        self.self_attention = SelfAttention(some_args)
        self.out_layer = nn.Linear(arg2, 1)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.inp_layer(x)
        x = self.self_attention(x)
        x = self.out_layer(x)
        return x
```

After loading a checkpoint of `ActualModel`, in `ActualModel.__init__` during continuing-training or during prediction time should I load a saved model checkpoint of class `SelfAttention`?

If I create an instance of class `SelfAttention`, would the trained weights corresponding to `SelfAttention.multihead_attn` be loaded if I do `torch.load(actual_model.pth)` or would be they be reinitialized?

In other words, is this necessary?

```
class ActualModel(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.inp_layer = nn.Linear(arg1, arg2)
        self.self_attention = SelfAttention(some_args)
        self.out_layer = nn.Linear(arg2, 1)
        
    def pred_or_continue_train(self):
        self.self_attention = torch.load('self_attention.pth')

actual_model = torch.load('actual_model.pth')
actual_model.pred_or_continue_training()
actual_model.eval()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In other words, is this necessary?

In short, **No**.

The `SelfAttention` class will be automatically loaded if it has been registered as a nn.module, nn.Parameters, or manually registered buffers.

A quick example:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class SelfAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, fin, n_h):
        super(SelfAttention, self).__init__()
        self.multihead_attn = torch.nn.MultiheadAttention(fin, n_h)
        
    def foward(self, x):
        return self.multihead_attn.forward(x, x, x)
    
class ActualModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ActualModel, self).__init__()
        self.inp_layer = nn.Linear(10, 20)
        self.self_attention = SelfAttention(20, 1)
        self.out_layer = nn.Linear(20, 1)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.inp_layer(x)
        x = self.self_attention(x)
        x = self.out_layer(x)
        return x

m = ActualModel()
for k, v in m.named_parameters():
    print(k)
```

You will get as follows, where `self_attention` is successfully registered.

```
inp_layer.weight
inp_layer.bias
self_attention.multihead_attn.in_proj_weight
self_attention.multihead_attn.in_proj_bias
self_attention.multihead_attn.out_proj.weight
self_attention.multihead_attn.out_proj.bias
out_layer.weight
out_layer.bias
```